# How to manage my site appearance in serp like this examples?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-results

So for example when you Google the name "Microsoft", you'll see a sidebar on the right showing information and links etc., and below the main link on the left, you see the main categories of the company.

How can I do the same for my own site? Who decides on this though? Google itself or the team behind the site uses some SEO stuff to appear like that?

Comment: This is determined by Google, but setting up Google My Business can help Google with this.